# Confusion about Character Pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

The character pointers in C is confusing me.

Suppose we have a char pointer, which points to the first character of string **constant**.

```
char *a="ABCD";
```

Then we cannot change the value of that character using the pointer a, as following statement results in a segmentation fault.

```
*a='X';
```

Now suppose we have a char pointer, which points to a character **constant**.

```
const char B='X';    
char *ptr=&B;
```

Then we are allowed to change the value of that character using the statement

```
*ptr='Z';
```

My question is that is this a case of undefined behaviour proving C is not robust? Or is there some deeper logic involved?

Comment: @EugeniuRosca you mean `char const *a = "ABCD"`. They don't have the same semantics.

Comment: const means that the memory is readonly.  Period.  You are not allowd to change it by referencing  it through another pointer - this should generate a compiler warning.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the pointer behaves differently is that C program has several memory segments, some of which are protected.

> Then we cannot change the value of that character using the pointer a, as following statement results in a segmentation fault.

Unlike other constants, string constants are placed into a protected segment. Any attempt to modify this segment results in undefined behavior (i.e. your program could segfault).

Since your pointer points into a string constant, the value to which it points cannot be modified. If you force a copy of the constant into modifiable memory by using an array, the same modification would be allowed:

```
char a[]="ABCD";
*a='X';
```

> Then we are allowed to change the value of that [single] character using the statement

This is because character constant is always copied into modifiable memory.

Answer (score 7):

Let's say that C lets you shoot yourself in the foot quite easily. Modifying `B` is still undefined behaviour though, just as modifying `*a` was, because `B` has been declared `const`.

To help with this, turning on warnings (which you should **always** do unless under very specific circumstances) brings up the following on GCC :

```
warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer
         target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
```

Answer (score 5):

In C, modification of string literal is not allowed.

```
char *a="ABCD";
```

is equivalent to

```
char const *a="ABCD";
```

`*a='X';` is modifying the string literal `ABCD`. While in second case, `ptr` is pointing to a character which do not supposed to be changed and `*ptr='Z';` will modifying the content of the location that contains `X` which is also not valid.

Note that modifying a `const` qualified object is a constraint violation.

Comment: Modifying `*ptr` is not valid in the slightest.

Comment: @Quentin; Oops! Agreed. Missed that `const` specifier.