# sizeof character pointer confusion

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    double a;
    double b[10];
    char *c;
    char r[12]="appleeeeeee";
    c=r;

cout<<sizeof c<<endl;     //Why is this 8 and not equal  to 12 i.e sizeof(r)    
cout<<sizeof r; 
}
```

q1. Isn't the array name a pointer to the beginning of the array?? If so then why does the sizeof operator evaluates to two different values in the above code.

i.e Why `sizeof c` yields 8 while `sizeof r` yields 12 even though both of them are pointer to a character.

Why is the size of the array `r[12]` printed in the second case?

this question may look like the duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943909/confusion-about-character-pointers-in-c)  but it doesnt answer my question.

Comment: @DietmarKühl i think the duplicate you provided helped. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, an array decays to a pointer to the first element.  This is **not** the case however for the `sizeof` operator.  It can distinguish between an array and a pointer and give the correct value.  Since `c` is a pointer to a `char` the value you're getting is the size of a pointer.  The fact that `c` contains the address of the first element of `r` doesn't matter.

Also, value of the `sizeof` operator is computed at compile time, so whatever value a variable might have is not relevant to `sizeof`.  The only exception is for variable length arrays in C.

Comment: "value of the sizeof operator is computed at compile time, so whatever value a variable might have is not relevant to sizeof" this perfectly explains why sizeof(c) would print 1 regardless of the value its pointing to but Can you explain further on why sizeof(r) evaluates to 12. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof c` is reporting the size of the *pointer*, not what it points to (you're on a system with 64 bit pointers, thus a size of 8 to hold a pointer). Even `sizeof *c` wouldn't help, because the pointer is to the first element of `r`, not the "array", so `sizeof *c` would just report the same thing as `sizeof r[0]`, that is `1`.